# HTML to PDF converter by jspdf, Bg color issue

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, canvas, jspdf

I am using canvas and jspdf to convert from html to pdf

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="html2canvas.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf.debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        html2canvas(document.body).then(function(canvas) {

            document.getElementById("cisForm").appendChild(canvas);
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);

            //var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
          var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
          context.fillStyle = '#fff';

          //window.location = canvas.toDataURL("pdf");
          var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');              
          var doc = new jsPDF();
            doc.addImage(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"),"jpeg",0,0)
         window.location=doc.output("datauristring")


        });
        }
    </script>
```

It gives the PDF but the background color is black.

How can I remove bg color from pdf?

Answer (score 0):

Add background:"#fff" in html2canvas options.